# Importing Adam and ImageDataGenerator on google colab failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, google-colaboratory

I'm implementing a UNet neural network but I'm having some issues while importing libraries. I found a solution for a couple of them, but I still have a problem with these two imports:

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
#Import "tensorflow.keras.optimizers" could not be resolved(reportMissingImports)

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
#Import "tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image" could not be resolved(reportMissingImports)
```

I've already imported:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

Any idea? I've tried to change but it still raises an error.

Comment: Could you try again running the same code after reopening the new `colab notebook` and closing all other open notebooks. Let us know if the issue still persists.

Comment: the problem was the tensorflow version!Now Adam works only on the nightly and after installing it works fine